# VBA Range Issues - Set and Dynamic

Tags: vba, excel, object, range

Update: Just need to learn how to make fullrng dynamic

Big Picture:
I am trying to automatically create named ranges based on the data in a column.

The subprocedure I have posted takes an element of an array as an argument. All of this logic works fine.. I can create the named ranges for each element of the array.

I figured out the logic of how to get the values that I want in my range.

the for rownum = 2 to finalrow
next row

contains this logic.

The problem is that I am having trouble with the ranges.

If I dont use Set my ranges = Range(cells) then i get an object error.. this makes sense, the object has been declared but not set to anything.

**I just dont know how to get these ranges initialized, and then change them to the group of cells that I want to**

**fullrng also needs to be dynamic** is will be 2 cells tall, then 3 , then 4, etc.

```
Sub Createranges(ByVal TableName As String)

 If TableName <> "" Then

    Debug.Print TableName
    Dim fullrng As Range
    Dim temprng As Range
    Dim thiscell As Range
    Dim nextcell As Range

    Set fullrng = Range("H1")

    fullrng.Name = TableName

        For rownum = 2 To finalrow

            'Checking to see if cell should be in named range
            If Cells(rownum, ColumnVar).Value = TableName Then

                'Modify Ranges for union
                Set thiscell = Range(ColumnVar & Cells.Row, ColumnVar & Cells.Column)
                Set nextcell = Range(ColumnVar & Cells.Row + 1, ColumnVar & Cells.Column)

                'union the range to include all past matching values
                If thiscell.Value2 = nextcell.Value2(2, 1) Then
                    Set temprng = Range(thiscell, nextcell)
                    'Figure out dynamic ranges here
                    Set fullrng = Range(
                    fullrng = Union(fullrng, temprng)
                End If

            End If

        Next rownum
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Would that do the trick?

Comment: If you are setting a range (even through re-assignment) you need to use the Set keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were alot of problems!

I guess thats what you get when you don't create your own objects, you have to explore and figure out the object model.

Besides some things being blatantly wrong --- using Cells.Column instead of my ColumnVar & rownum variables, here is what I changed:

I was originally Setting my range to a random cell so that I could name my range. fullrng.Name = TableName I just moved this line to right after I set the fullrng.

```
Sub Createranges(ByVal TableName As String)

If TableName <> "" Then

Debug.Print TableName
Dim fullrng As Range
Dim temprng As Range
Dim thiscell As Range
Dim nextcell As Range


    For rownum = 2 To finalrow

        'Checking to see if cell should be in named range
        If Cells(rownum, ColumnVar).Value = TableName Then

            'Modify Ranges for union
            Set thiscell = Range(ColumnVar & rownum, ColumnVar & rownum)
            Set nextcell = Range(ColumnVar & rownum + 1, ColumnVar & rownum + 1)

            'union the range to include all past matching values
            If thiscell.Text = nextcell.Text Then
                Set temprng = Application.Union(thiscell, nextcell)
                If Not fullrng Is Nothing Then
                    Set fullrng = Application.Union(fullrng, temprng)
                    fullrng.Name = TableName
                Else
                    Set fullrng = temprng
                End If

            End If

        End If

    Next rownum
End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There are bugs in your and all of the is because your assigning a range object in an incorrect way.

this line is not good

```
Set temprng = Range(thiscell, nextcell)
```

`thiscell` and `nextcell` are already ranges. You should use `Union` to combine them:

```
set temrange=application.union(thiscell, nextcell)
```

the same way change this part:

```
 set fullrange=application.union(fullrng,temprange)
```

as an improvement, you have to always make sure before unsing `Union` that both ranges that you are combining are defined (`is not nothing`)

for example, the first time that the above line is executed, `fullrange` may be nothing which will throw an error, to avoide do this:

```
if not fullrange is nothing then
    set fullrange=application.union(fullrng,temprange)
else
    set fullrange=temprange
end if
```